# Infinite oscillation of minimum word length in 2-generated group

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Let $G$ be a group with generators $a, b\in G$.

Define $\mathrm{len}:G\to\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ by sending $g$ to the minimum length of a word in $a, b, a^{-1}, b^{-1}$ equal to $g$.

Assume that for all $g\neq e\in G$ there is infinitely many $n\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ such that $\mathrm{len}(g^{n+1})<\mathrm{len}(g^n)$.

Must every element of $G$ be of finite order then?

Comment: It would be enough to produce a nontrivial torsion-free 2-generated group in which every element is more than exponentially distorted (in the sense that for every $g$, the function $n\mapsto\sup\{m:|g^m|\le n\}$ is supraexponential). This is possibly known or available by current known methods.

Comment: @YCor: how about Osin's group with 2 conjugacy classes? I would  be very surprised if the (unique up to conjugacy) cyclic subgroup were not very distorted!

Comment: @HJRW this is correct! I then wrote an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer is partly inspired by HJRW's comment.

**Definition 1.** Let $G$ be a finitely generated group and $g\in G$, and word length $|\cdot|$ with respect to some finite generating subset. Say that $g$ is very distorted if $\liminf |g^n|/\log(n)=0$, or equivalently if $u_g(n)=\sup\{m:|g^m|\le n\}$ satisfies $\limsup\log(u_g(n))/n=\infty$.

It is not hard to check that this implies that $|g^n|>|g^{n+1}|$ for infinitely many $n$ (otherwise the growth would be more than exponential).

**Proposition.** Let $G$ be a finitely generated group with finitely many conjugacy classes. Then every element $g$ of $G$ is very distorted.

Proof: if $g$ has finite order this is trivial. Otherwise, $g$ has infinite order. Then there exists $n>1$ and $h\in G$ such that $hgh^{-1}=g^n$. Hence $h^kgh^{-k}=g^{n^k}$ for all $k$, and hence $h$ has infinite order. In turn there exists $f\in G$ and $m>1$ such that $fhf^{-1}=h^m$, so $|f^khf^{-k}|=|h^{m^k}|=O(k)$. In turn, $|h^{m^k}gh^{-m^k}|=|g^{n^{m^k}}|=O(k)$. Hence $\liminf |g^k|/\log\log k<\infty$, so $g$ is very distorted.

The existence of torsion-free finitely generated groups with finitely many conjugacy classes was proved by Ivanov in the late 80s, and later Osin found examples with two conjugacy classes (I think both can be chosen generated by a pair). So this answers the question.